# Fascia installation on a gable roof

Tags: roof, saw, angle

I'm building a small Tiki bar in my backyard and already framed my gable roof at 3-12 pitch. All the rafters are plumb cut.

On the front of the structure, the ridge beam protrudes out 4 feet. I want to run a fascia board from the front rafter to the ridge board. This is a 55 degree angle rather than a 90 degree, and the vertical angle from the rafter to the ridge beam is 10 degrees.

My saw only goes to 45 degrees miter. Can someone help me to understand the way to cut these compound cuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different tool.

Set your circular saw to a 10° bevel, mark your board for the 55° angle, then cut along the line. If the saw doesn't bevel the "right" way, then cut from the other side of the board.

If you're not sure of your circular saw skills, cut a bit proud of the line, then work your way to it. As you make a couple of cuts, you'll get better. So long as you don't cut into the "keep" piece, you can sand to the line as necessary.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfect. Measure 5 times, cut once!